Arrayformula with Query in Google Sheets
I tried to get ARRAYFORMULA in Google Sheets to automatically fill the cells below with the formula. The following code only works for the first row.
Can I ask for help?


=ArrayFormula( Query(DatenTime!$A$2:$O; "Select sum(L) WHERE O ="&O10&" AND N ="&N10&" label sum(L) ''") )




QUERY is not the right function for this, use SUMIF.
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIF(DatenTime!O:O&DatenTime!N:N,O10:O&N10:N,DatenTime!L:L))

